# colorbox to load ajax content, how to retrieve querystring values with or without jquery sent to the ajax .htm page

Tags: colorbox

I know how to load ajax content "winner.htm" using colorbox; however, I need to send via querystring "?fund=Aggregate" to the "winner.htm" page.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) if you need a hint on how to retrieve querystring values via jQuery (or without)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I look into this last night, I found that it was because accessing windows.location.href using javascript in the external ajax file will only return the invoking window's url since colorbox is only a popup, an overlay, so the common solution will not work.
And I finally solve this by accessing not a .htm file but a .aspx file and get the passed-in querystrings in the code-behind :)